# SQL 2005 Replication error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication

I'm trying to change the maximum transaction retention period in our SQL2005 tranasaction replication environment from the default 72 hours to 120.

Either through T-SQL or GUI I get the following message:

Msg 14294, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_verify_job_identifiers, Line 25
Supply either @job_id or @job_name to identify the job.

The T-SQL I'm running is a as follows:

sp_changedistributiondb @database = 'distribution', @property = 'max_distretention', @value = 120

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code below is what's failing. I got this by running sp_helptext sp_changedistributiondb  & also looking at what sproc's call sp_verify_job_identifiers.

It looks like changedistributiondb is having trouble updating the distribution cleanup agent job when it runs sp_update_jobstep :

```
SELECT @command =  'EXEC dbo.sp_MSdistribution_cleanup @min_distretention = ' + 
                CONVERT(nvarchar(12), @new_min_distretention) + ', @max_distretention = ' +
                CONVERT(nvarchar(12), @max_distretention)
            EXEC @retcode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_jobstep @job_name = @agentname, @step_id = 1, 
                @command = @command
```

maybe this job has been deleted or there is something else strange going on, either way, you should be able to modify the job step manually.

**EDIT:** The cleanup agent runs on the server with the distribution database. It removes replication history and runs every 10 minutes by default. The job should look like this: 
**name:** *Agent history clean up: distribution*
**category:** REPL-History Cleanup
**steps:** (1)Run Agent 
**database:** distribution  
**command:**EXEC dbo.sp_MShistory_cleanup @history_retention = 48

Comment: Thanks Nick, it looks like the distribution clean-up job is missing. Any ideas on how to recreate it? Can't remember it being there - perhaps I'm running a configuration where it isn't required - distributor co-located with publisher?

Comment: i think it's always required

Comment: Thanks Nick - this is a pre-production environment, I removed and recreated the replication and the job has been re-created.